# ASP.NET MVC routing issue: How to allow "\" in id's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, escaping

I am using following route map

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "RenderAssociatedForm",
  "DoAction/{nodeLevelId}/{nodeSystemId}",
  new {
    controller = "FrontEnd",
    action = "RenderAssociatedForm",                    
});
```

Now `nodeLevelId` can be anything like `zs\bbal`. As we know that we should escape '\', so we are using 'zs%5cbbal'. But still the following url is not mapping to this route.

`//localhost/DoAction/zs%5cbbal/5`

When I try simple Id without the escape character, it maps properly. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: It's the new year, and most people are still spending time with their families.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with two routes. The first route would be the one you showed, and the one **after** it would simply have `"DoAction/{nodeLevelId}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use wildcards and parse the values out yourself:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "RenderAssociatedForm",
        "DoAction/{*nodeLevelId}/{nodeSystemId}",
        new
        {
            controller = "FrontEnd",
            action = "RenderAssociatedForm",                    
        });
```

Comment: Sorry it will not work. It gives you the error "A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route URL"

Comment: @Bipul, rearrange your route then.  There is only one way to have a slash in a url.  Maybe even replace them with dashes?

Answer (score -2):

@jfar probably has the best solution. Substitute the \ for a - or $ or something more URL friendly.